# connecting to a table created under serverless dynamoDB using springboot

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, aws-serverless, dynamodb-queries

There a table created using serverless.yml in dynamo.
Im trying to connect to the table created. But sice i have always used a domin name to configure to the table. Since this table does not have a domain name. How can i set my configurations to connect to this table using springboot.